# Excel VBA prevent VBA from converting Time values to decimals

Tags: datetime, excel, vba

I am trying to extract data from my workbook because I made the workbook wrong but I want to keep the data. So I have to go through each worksheet and extract the specific bits of data I need. (Repetitive task = vba code to the rescue)

I'm done, but I have one nasty little problem.

I am using ws.Range("C13") to extract each cell that I need. It's a cell that has time values like 10:00 or 22:13. When I debug.print that value however I get a decimal. Why? How do I prevent it from converting my "10:30" to "0.4375"

From what I can tell, the decimal isn't even related to the time value. 
WRONG it is simply the time value as a representation of a 24 hour period. So it is related. But still.

Comment: Since it is a time value equivalent all you need to do is understand that the this is how excel stores/interprets the data and you just need to format it to format you need.

Comment: If you want to turn the Excel time-code value into a string literal, you can use the TEXT function with the appropriate time format. For example, `=TEXT(C13,"hh:mm am/pm")` with the time-code 0.452778 in cell C13 would produce the string "10:52 am".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time values are correct; it's the way Excel stores date and time values internally.

Dates are stored as floating point values, where the whole portion represents the number of days since `12/30/1899 00:00.00` (date `0.0`) and the decimal part represents the fractional part of a single day (eg., `408875.5` represents `11/28/2011  12:00:00 PM`).

Here are some conversion factors you might find useful:

```
Decimal value    Time Value    Calculation 
=============    ==========    ===========
0.00094444444    12:01:00 AM   1.0 / 24 / 60 (1 day/24 hours/60 minutes per hour)
0.01041666666    12:15:00 AM   1.0 / 24 / 60 * 15
0.02083333333    12:30:00 AM   1.0 / 24 / 60 * 30
0.04166666666    01:00:00 AM   1.0 / 24
```

Answer (score 7):

`ws.Range("C13")` is the equivalent of `ws.Range("C13").Value` which returns the underlying data from that cell.

If instead you use `ws.Range("C13").Text`, you will get the displayed text from the cell. If you have set a specific date/time format for that cell then calling `ws.Range("C13").Text` should return text in that specific format

Comment: While the accepted answer has the technical method of calculating the time values, I thought from a pragmatic point of view, this answer did the trick. All I want is the Text Representation.

Answer (score 0):

```
hours        = MOD(INT(0.tttttttt*24), 24)
minutes      = MOD(INT(0.tttttttt*24*60), 60)
seconds      = MOD(INT(0.tttttttt*24*60*60), 60)
milliseconds = MOD(INT(0.tttttttt*24*60*60*1000), 1000)
```