# DATE showing in TIME format cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this strange problem, my `Column D` has time in it and I have set its format as `TIME 13:00:00`

It displays exact way I want to, but in formula bar it also displays the Date from `Column A`

**My format is:**

```
Date      | Time   | Table | Checkin Time 
6/1/2018   16:21:55  55       16:21:55
```

When I click on values under `Checkin Time`, it shows `Date + Time`

[image: screenshot]

I also tried copying and pasting as plain text but got the same result.

Comment: You have a datetime value but have chosen to only display the time portion through cell formatting. What's unclear about that? IMO, this is preferred as it makes calculation across midnight easier.

Comment: @Jeeped Column is displaying `TIME` only, thats fine. But in formula bar its showing both `Date & Time ` . It will create problem to apply `formula` later when I ll be using to calculate difference between ` Col D & Col B `

Comment: If column B is the same then it will be easier. If column B is 'time only', then you would have to add a date to it in any event. Think of `02:30:00` in column D (actually 19-Sep-2018 02:30:00) and you want to subtract `23:15:00` in column B (actually 18-Sep-2018 23:15:00). It's a simple subtraction. Only if one or both of columns B and D do not have a date factor is it complicated.

Comment: Yes `Column B ` is Time only . Thats why to make it even, I want to remove `Date` from `Column D ` .

Comment: The time is the decimal portion of the raw underlying value2. You can use `=MOD(D2, 1)` to extract it. Remember to add 1 to column D's value if column D is less than column B.

Comment: The formula bar is showing the actual value in the cell,which is exactly what it should be showing. It would be absolutely wrong if it showed you anything else than what it actually contains in the cell. It makes no sense to think it would show anything else than what is really in the cell. Think about it. If you put a floating point value there and choose to display it with a format that doesn't show the fractional portion, that portion is still in the cell and affects any math you do with that cell. It exists, whether you choose to show it or not.

Comment: @KenWhite Thats Why i posted the question for the solution, How do make it only `TIME` .

Comment: You can't, because Excel stores datetime values as floating point numbers. The number representing time only would be 0.xxxx, where the time is the fractional portion of a day. Try formatting `0.01` as a date and time in Excel, and you'll be back in the year 1899. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15373661/62576) I wrote a while back that explains. Also see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20128245/62576)

Comment: @KenWhite So only way I can see is to `=CONCATENATE()` the `Col A` and `Col B` to match the format of `Col E ` and do the `DIFFERENCE` ?

Comment: You would simply add column A and column B together, not concatenate them.

Comment: @KenWhite If that so, then why is `Col B` showing only `TIME` ? but not `Date and time ` like `Col D ` ?

Comment: I've given you two separate links that explain how Excel stores and handles dates and times. Have you read them?

Comment: @Jeeped you deleted the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From the comments, it looks like you are trying to answer two questions:**

1. How do I remove the "Date" from the "Datetime" so I only see "Time" in the formula bar?
2. How do I calculate the difference between two times?

I'll answer question 2 first, because then you might realise you don't need the answer to question 1:

---

**Question 2: How do I calculate the difference between two times?**

As you can see in the screenshot below, I used this formula:

```
=TEXT(B3-C3,"h:mm")
```

[image: Time Difference]

Also notice, B3 is formatted as a "Datetime" and C3 is formatted as a "Time," and we still get the correct result. For this reason you probably don't need the answer to Question 1 above, because you don't need to remove the "Date" part out of a "Datetime" to calculate the difference.

There is more information [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/06/24/calculate-time-excel/) on different ways to format your output.

---

**Question 1: How do I remove the "Date" from the "Datetime" so I only see "Time" in the formula bar?**

As @Jeeped kindly pointed out in the comments:

> The time is the decimal portion of the raw underlying value2. You can use `=MOD(D2, 1)` to extract it. Remember to add 1 to column D's value if column D is less than column B

Comment: :) . Thank you so much.. I remember you @girlvsdata . you solved my previous such excel post too. I am stuck in new one, its half solved but bigger problem can oyu help me on this ? [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52396984/get-value-of-first-pair/52397313#52397313)